# How to get email for unauthorized sudo attempts?

Tags: sudo, email, logs

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641049/who-are-incidents-really-reported-to-and-how-can-a-sudo-user-access-the-reports) question, unauthorized attempts to sudo are saved in `/var/log/auth.log` and by default, *a mail is sent to* `/dev/null`. Is there any way to prevent that from happening and send the mail to an actual domain?

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup sudo to write mails as stated on the page you have linked.

In your `/etc/sudoers` add `mailto your@e.mail` and the option when to send mails, in your case `mail_badpass`.

Comment: [Where](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14140673/) in the `sudoers` file?

Comment: You already have `mail_badpass` in there, so you can just put the your e-mail address before it.

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of Ubuntu (at least 21.10) suggest adding sudo configs into the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory. One can still add this in the `/etc/sudoers` file (remember to use `visudo`.)

Succinctly, to do what you want:

`/etc/sudoers.d/mail-sysadmin`

```
Defaults    mailto="email@example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop these e-mails when you type a wrong password you could also

- type the correct password
- use a password manager
- use a password-less setup (see https://serverfault.com/a/160587/98708)

I guess you want an e-mail when someone else (e.g. *Mallory*) is using the wrong password to use sudo.